# PHP MySQL SUM mulitple-columns with 0/1 marker in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sum, multiple-columns

I like to build a summary from my database.

Table:writenquotes

```
id|  datum   |member|transaktion |pm|beträge
1 |1372456800|Name1 |transaktion1|0 |  24
2 |1372543200|Name2 |transaktion1|1 |  24
```

With my Code:

```
<?php
include("dbopen.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(beträge)
FROM writenquotes");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['SUM(beträge)'];
}
?>
```

My problem is, the PM declares the positive or negative figures with 0 or 1.

0 = positive figures

1 = negative figures

With my code, I can build only a positive summary e.g. 48...

id 1 = 24 ( positive )

id 2 = -24 ( negative )

The summary it would be real 0 and not 48

Don't know what is my mistake but my code gives me only a 0 ( Zero ) or a Resource id #3 ... umpf :-(

```
<?php
include("dbopen.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(IF(pm=1, -1, 1) * beträge) FROM  writenquotes", $link);
echo mysql_errno($link) . " " . mysql_error($link). "\n";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<font color=\"red\">".$row['SUM(beträge)']."</font>";
}
?>
```

And this

```
<?php
include("dbopen.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(CASE pm=0 THEN beträge ELSE -beträge END) FROM writenquotes", $link);
echo mysql_errno($link) . " " . mysql_error($link). "\n";
echo $result['SUM(beträge)'];
?>
```

gives me only this:

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'THEN beträge ELSE -beträge END) FROM writenquotes' at line 1

Comment: **i can build only a positive a summary e.g. 48...** What do you mean by that?

Comment: id 1 = 24 ( positiv )
id 2 = -24 ( negativ )
the summary it would be real 0 and not 48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just multiply by `-1` for each rows with `pm = 1`. Also use alias for selected value to access it easier:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(IF(pm=1, -1, 1) * beträge) AS my_sum FROM writenquotes";
...
echo $row['my_sum'];
```

Comment: Yeah thats right...
I stood on the line :-)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CASE` construct for that:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE pm=0 THEN beträge ELSE -beträge END)
FROM writenquotes
```